# Are there any good ssh consoles for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, ssh

I'm looking for a good ssh console plugin for Eclipse, and can't find much at all. Would anyone have some good leads on one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Eclipse 3.4.1, there is the Remote Systems Explorer perspective that allows you to create and connect to SSH terminals ([here](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/tutorial/))

Comment: Checked it out... not good. If you do e.g. "top" it scrolls and behaves weird.

Comment: I tested out both of the terminal 'subsystems' included in Eclipse's RSE, and I didn't like them.  From the Remote systems view, I tried both 'SSH Shells' and 'SSH Terminals'.  ssh.shells had an annoying input box at the bottom, and ssh.terminals was better but I couldn't change the background color, and had scrolling issues.

After this, I tried the 'Terminal' view, and was able to fix both problems!  (I ran out of characters here, so my solution is posted below)

Comment: Found that there's an open Eclipse [bug 206220](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=206220) for the color issue.

Comment: Remote Systems Explorer does not support text search within the terminal. That is a major drawback for me.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't like the ssh.shells or ssh.terminals subsystems in Eclipse RSE, try using the Terminal View instead.

- Open up Window -> Show View -> Other (or press `Shift+Alt+Q` then `Q`)
- Type *`Terminal`* in the search box
- Select the *`Terminal`* view listed under the *`Terminal`* folder

You'll see a window that looks similar to RSE's ssh.terminals subsystem... but with some extra buttons on the top right.

### How to use it:

- To fix the scrolling issue (ie: for programs like `top`), click the *`Scroll Lock`* button at the right.
- For extra Terminal window tabs, click the down arrow on the *`New Terminal Connection`* button
- To change the current terminal window's settings, use the *`Settings`* button.
- If you really like the annoying command input box at the bottom, you can toggle it on and off with the appropriate button.

### Change the Background Color:

For some reason, the default setting is to use a terribly hard to see white background.  To change this:

- Go to Window -> Preferences
- Type *`Terminal`* in the search box at the top left, or select *`Terminal`* on the left.
- Check the box that says *`Invert terminal colors`*
- You can also configure a larger terminal buffer or connection timeouts here
- Click *`Apply`*

Now the terminal should have a black background!  If you want a local terminal, you can enable ssh on your local machine, and connect to `localhost`.

Comment: You're welcome!  It definitely took me a while to figure all this out, but now I'm finally happy with the Eclipse terminal.  Now if only java would redraw the screen faster so scrolling doesn't flash so much ;-)

Comment: If you are using Linux, I'd also recommend `yakuake` as an alternative *always ready* terminal that won't take up screen space when not in use.

Comment: If on Mac OS X, a similar _always ready_ terminal is [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) in hotkey mode (Check both options in Preferences -> Keys -> `Show/hide iterm2 with a system-wide hotkey` / `Hotkey toggles a dedicated window with profile: Hotkey Window`

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins that exist that allow you up open WinSCP or Putty from within Eclipse.

I would advise maybe doing a search for "putty eclipse plugin" or similar

Comment: Funny, this question is now the 2nd ranked term on google for an unquoted search of "putty eclipse plugin"

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [Terminal plug-in for Eclipse](https://code.google.com/p/elt/)

> This plug-in provides a fully-working, command-line terminal to
>   Eclipse 3.7 or later (yes, even 4.2!) It works on Linux and MacOS
>   only.

More info at: http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=2428