# Running console application remotely in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I there a way (plugin) in eclipse that can run (console) application over ssh (of course do a synchronize before that with something like rsync), and display results in standard console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh)

Comment: You could tag your question a little better. It will help it get more visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

[best-sftp-plugin-eclipse](http://www.freshblurbs.com/best-sftp-plugin-eclipse)

[eclipse-sftp](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/)

[eclipse-cvsssh2](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-cvsssh2/)

[eclipsesshconsole](http://eclipsetail.sourceforge.net/eclipsesshconsole.html)

Also take a look at: [are-there-any-good-ssh-consoles-for-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334342/are-there-any-good-ssh-consoles-for-eclipse)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also **run Eclipse remotely**.

It should be fairly easy: use `ssh -Y server_ip` to connect to it, execute `eclipse &` and it will have direct access to the filesystem.

Of course, this solution is only practical if you have a decent network connection to the remote PC since GUI processing will be handled by the other machine (not yours).

Anyway, someone asked a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216822/work-on-a-remote-project-with-eclipse-via-ssh/4216878#4216878). Take a look at the answer.