# Remote Eclipse Development with VM

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging

I'm developing a Maven Project in a Virtual Machine and would like to use the full Eclipse functionality on the host system, including refactoring and debugging and ideally execution of Maven Commands from the IDE.

Is there any way to use something like headless Eclipse and connect to it from my local IDE (not using eclim that is)?

Right now my work around would be to mount the file system with SSHFS (as I didn't find a way to work completely in sync with RSE), import into Eclipse and run mvnDebug.

If someone has a more elegant or standarized hands on approach, I'd be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you use [eclim](http://eclim.org/) on the guest system, right? What's wrong with it? What feature/functionality do you need that it doesn't support?

Comment: I was looking for an approach to use normal, graphical Eclipse IDE instead of VIM and debug and edit as if I were running it directly in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing Eclipse projects located on an other host reqiures file access. You do this with SSHFS already. I'm not aware of any other way to accomplish this atm.

See [Are there any good ssh consoles for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334342/are-there-any-good-ssh-consoles-for-eclipse) for executing commands on an other host.

For remote debugging see:

- [Maven Surefire Plugin , Debugging Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html), in short: `mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test`
- [Javarevisited, How to setup Java remote debugging in Eclipse](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html).